# Search by filetype in sublimetext3

Tags: search, sublimetext, file-extension, file-type, typing

I know that it is possible to filter a search query in sublime to only look at/through certain filetypes, but I don't remember the syntax to do so. As far as I can recall, it was something like

```
..//filepath/ *.scss, *.css, *.xckv, -*.etc
```

Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type '`MAJ+Ctrl+F`'

You see the input at bottom of screen.

```
Line 1 : Find Input
Line 2 : Where Input
Line 3 : Replace Input
```

At right of `Where` Input, click on the three dots, and select '`add Include Filter`'